# Code Behind calling a JavaScript function on a button click - C#

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Js function which calls the bootstrap modal popup. I'm calling this Js function from code behind on a button click. The problem is when I click on the button it is showing the modal popup, but when I navigate to another page(When I click on another button,It navigates to a google document reader) and come back to the home page, it is again loading the popup without any button click. Can anyone help me with this.

#### JS function

```
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
            function showModal() {
                $('#viewOc').modal();
            };
    </script>
</head>
```

#### Modal Popup code

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="viewOc" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4>TRIAL</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    LOREM IPSUM
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">
                        Close
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

#### Code behind

```
 protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
            {
                //some operations here
                string script = "window.onload = function() { showModal(); };";
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "modalShow", script, true); 
            }
```

#### Html code

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text="Click Here" CausesValidation="false" commandArgument='<%#Eval("value")%>' OnCommand="LinkButton1_Click"/>
```

#### Google Docs button click event

```
 protected void btnView_View(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
        {
            //not sure if the below code is correct or wrong. But as of now im using this in my application. Didnt try it on server yet.
            string path = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
            Response.Redirect("http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=" + Server.UrlEncode(path),true);
        }
```

#### Page Load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                IndexDocuments();

            }
        }
```

P.S : I know similar question but with a different problem is asked in SO. As I dont have enough reputation to comment on that question, I had to make a new post.

Answer (score 0):

you should call the model on button click

```
$('buttonID').click(function(){ $('modalID').modal('show'); });
```

you are calling the modal on window.onload thats why it is showing pop up when page load.

Comment: Do I have to change this in the code behind or in the JS Function?

Comment: make changes in JS, just write $('buttonID').click(function(){ $('#viewOc').modal('show'); }); , no need to call it from code behind when you no need to show any dynamic data in modal, JS will do all the job.

Comment: So I just need to make this change in JS and leave the button click event as it is and remove the call method?

Comment: Nope. I tried the same. It is not opening any modal popup

Comment: But I need to get some data from code behind and then show it on modal popup.. so I think i cannot use the method u said

Answer (score 0):

Vishal has mentioned below a better approach to handle that.

$('buttonID').click(function(){ $('modalID').modal('show'); });

Instead of using an ASP button, you can use a normal HTML button with the above code.

Thanks,
Souvik

Comment: `protected void btnView_View(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
        {
            string path = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
            Response.Redirect("http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=" + Server.UrlEncode(path),true); }`

Answer (score 0):

You're binding showModal() every time the window loads.
Change the code-behind like this:

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
        {
            //some operations here
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "modalShow", "showModal()", true); 
        }
```

Comment: I tried this. But it never showed a modal popup if I use this code.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know you're using "ClientScript". It should work with ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript

Comment: I tried even this.. It doesnt show any modal popup.. I dont know why is it so. It is showing modal popup only when I used window.onLoad

Comment: I created a simple page with what you provided and It works for me. Can you see any error from the developer console (F12 if you're using Chrome)?

Comment: For me it is throwing an error like this.
**Home.aspx:277 Uncaught ReferenceError: showModal is not defined**

Comment: That's good. Can you place the showModal function declaration above the LinkButton in your html? Preferably at the top of the file

Comment: Okay.. I kept it in the header and tried. Now I'm getting **$ is not defined.** and pointing to this line ` $('#viewOc').modal();`

Comment: $ is not defined means jquery library is not found. Put the script tag for jquery, and bootstrap at the top as well (above the function declaration)

Comment: place your jquery and bootstrap js and css files at the top, before showModal function

Comment: Moved both these just below the <Title> Tag
`<link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />`
    `<script src="scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>`

After moving the jquery above the function call, I'm getting this error now. **Home.aspx:26 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function**

Comment: popup is working now.. But still facing the same issue. When i come back from the google docs page, it is loading the modal popup again without clicking anything

Comment: The interesting thing is, When i run the application and  instead of clicking on the modal popup button ,if i click the google docs reader button , it loads the google docs page and when i come back to Home.aspx it doesnt show any popup. But if i click on the popup button first, it shows the popup and after closing it, if I click on the google docs button, it navigates to google doc page and when i come back to Home.aspx , then it shows the pop up again without clicking on any button.

Comment: Can you post your "Page_Load" and the google doc button click event as well? I'm guessing the script block is also registered somewhere else.

Comment: Updated in the main question. you can have a look at it once.

Answer (score 0):

Add the js and css references

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>

<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        function showModal() {
            $('#viewOc').modal();
        };
</script>

</head>
```

Use this code:

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    //some operations here
    if(!ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("JSScript"))
    {
      ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"JSScript",
      @"<script type='text/javascript'>showModal()</script>");
    } 
}
```

Comment: Tried this. It is not opening any popup.

Comment: did you place your jquery and bootstrap js and css files at the top

Comment: yeah.. after placing them at the top I tried and I'm facing this issue. **$(...).modal is not a function**

Comment: did you check my updated answer as what all and where it has to be included. pls try that

Comment: Hi Karthik. After changing the positions of all the bootstrap.css, jquery and js scripts to the header, I tried both codes.. One is yours and and the other one is Neo Nguyen's.. Both are behaving the same way as i mentioned in Neo Nguyen's comments.. you can please have a look at those comments once.

Comment: How are you coming back to home page? by using back button or by clicking on home button?

Comment: By clicking the back button on the browser.

Comment: that is the problem, when you use back button, it will display the cached page. try to navigate to home page by clicking on the home button

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112244/discussion-between-asn-and-karthik-m-r).